# Use Laravel Backpack with regular users too

Tags: laravel, user-interface, laravel-backpack, laravel-8

I have this Laravel app that uses Backpack's CRUD so an admin can login and manage all the users, products, etc.
I would like to use Backpack to give all the regular users the possibility to see all the other users, products and other entities without giving them the capability of e.i. editing or deleting them, just to see them, possibility only given to the admins.
Is this possible? And how can I implement it?

Comment: have you made your own UserCrudController or AdminCrudController, if you did, please share it

Answer (score 1):

In your `CrudController setup()` do this:

```
class MyCrudController extends CrudController
{
    public function setup()
    {
        if (!$myTestCurrentUserIsAdmin) {
            $this->crud->denyAccess(['create', 'update', 'delete']);
        }
        ...
```

With ´denyAccess´ Backpack will automatically hide the edit links/buttons and protect the edit routes from using them.